# Confidence interval of two variances

Tags: self-study, confidence-interval

I have two normally distributed samples $[x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n]$ with sample variance $s^2_1$ and another sample  $[y_1, y_2,\ldots, y_n]$ with sample variance $s^2_2$.

I know how to calculate the confidence interval for each of the variances. However i do not know how to calculate the confidence interval of the sum of the two variances.

In other words, can someone help me to calculate the confidence interval for $\sigma^2_1+\sigma^2_2$.

Comment: This is a standard problem covered in statistics textbooks. Did you try consulting them first? You can ask then what in particular your did not understand.

Comment: Hi  mpiktas, Thx. I never studied statistics so i am not familiar with stat books. However, generally if something is in the book it is typically available in Google, but I failed to find anything in Google.  If you know the solution can u post it here and give me a link ...

Comment: Are $X$ and $Y$ independent? If so, what is the variance of $Z=X+Y$?

Comment: hi  soakley. Yes X and Y are independent: I assume you suggest to define Z=X+Y with var(Z)=var(X)+var(Y).

Can I now assume that Z is normally distributed and use the sample Z and apply the same technique to estimate the confidence interval for var(Z)?

Comment: is there any statistics guru here who can answer to my question? Some claim this to be a trivial problem, but i asked even some statistics graduate, but it si not a trivial problem....